# nested json to java objects List<Object> returns the expected values but List<DefinedObject> return null values

Tags: java, arrays, json, list

I have the following json that I would like to store it into java object:

```
{  
       "shippingDetails":{  
          "address":"khalda",
          "country":"Jordan",
          "town":"amman"
       },
       "product":[  
          {  
             "product":{  
                "id":2,
                "name":"Wrap Dress",
                "price":330,
                "salePrice":165,
                "discount":50,
                "pictures":[  
                   "assets/images/fashion/product/1.jpg",
                   "assets/images/fashion/product/1.jpg",
                   "assets/images/fashion/product/1.jpg",
                   "assets/images/fashion/product/1.jpg"
                ],
                "shortDetails":"test",
                "description":"test",
                "stock":2,
                "new":true,
                "sale":false,
                "category":"women",
                "colors":[  
                   "gray",
                   "orange"
                ],
                "size":[  
                   "M",
                   "L",
                   "XL"
                ],
                "tags":[  
                   "caprese",
                   "puma",
                   "lifestyle"
                ],
                "variants":[  
                   {  
                      "color":"gray",
                      "images":"assets/images/fashion/product/1.jpg"
                   },
                   {  
                      "color":"orange",
                      "images":"assets/images/fashion/product/1.jpg"
                   }
                ]
             },
             "quantity":1
          }
       ],
       "totalAmount":330
    }
```

And I have the following java beans for it:
The main object class called Order and it has

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order {
    @Id
    @Column(name="shippingDetailsId")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private ShippingDetails shippingDetails;
    //@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    //List<Product> products;
    List<Object> product = new ArrayList<>();
    private float totalAmount;
}
```

and the inner object classes are:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Product {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "productId")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @ManyToOne
    private Order order;
    private Boolean isNew;
    private String salePrice;
    private String shortDetails;
    private String discount;
    private String description;
    private Variants[] variants;
    private String[] pictures;
    private String[] colors;
    private String[] tags;
    private String sale;
    private String[] size;
    private String price;
    private String name;
    private String stock;
    private String category;
}
```

and the shipping details bean:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "shippingDetails")
public class ShippingDetails {
    @Id
    @Column(name="shippingDetailsId")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String address;
    private String country;
    private String town;
}
```

I have tried many ways but non of them worked, first I have tried to accept an Order object in my controller and try to store it but did not work, the results were:

when using List all the values are printed to the console as desired and inserted in the database but in the same table Orders, that's not what I'm looking for, I want the Products to be saved in a separate table called Products so I used List.

when used List the values of the product were null.

Then I have tried to accept a string in from my controller and use GSON library to convert it to the Order object but it did not work as well, I got many kind of exceptions trying to figure it out and tried many ways that were mentioned on stackoverflow and other websites but no luck, please not that I have validated my json string and it is a valid json.

Comment: What part is falling? Is it the conversion from JSON to Java Object or storing the Java Object to database? Also mention the exception without it, it is difficult to understand what is going wrong.

Comment: @subirKumarSao I have edited my question with the exceptions, Im still trying to convert the json to java object. I have reached a level where all the values in the product where inserted null to the database, but the shipping details and total amount were inserted successfully

Answer (score 1):

If you see the hierarchy in JSON it does not match your Java Object.

```
 "product":[  // Parent-Product
          {  
             "product":{  // Child-Product
                "id":2,
```

A direct mapping to Java would be something like

`List<Map<String,Product>> products`

If you have the option to change the JSON file then change to something like below and get rid of the Parent-Child Product hierarchy.

```
"product":[
  {
    "id":..
  },
  {
    "id":..
  }
  ..
]
```

Comment: List<Map<String,Product>> make so much sense but when I tried it I got compilation error says: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of '@'OneToMany or '@'ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class

Comment: @Khaled because hibernate cannot understand this complex hierarchy, either you change the JSON or write a custom parser to map the Product.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the converter here. It generates java objects from json. 
http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ (among others it supports, gson and jackson)

This will ensure that you have the correct mapping of Json to Java and vice versa.

Comment: I have tried such a tool but I got null values in my database, and even before inserting to the database, just by printing the values to the console the product values are null

Comment: It seems that the issue is coming from the Order.java for the field   "private Item product" and in the Item.java where you have List<Products> and also the private Order order.  I would recommend to start step by step to see exactly how you model it. 
Maybe a generator may help you, that's why I recommended to you.  Consider also that some fields must not be serialized/de-seriallized when converting to and from json. Maybe you can consider, remove Item.java and use only Order. java and Product.java (as ti is represented in json), and remove Item,java;

Comment: I have done that step by step, I figured out that my problem is in the product class, because when I use List<Object> it prints the values to the console, but when I use List<Product> I get the null values any suggestions with that please?